# Execute <script> from separate .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

Been working on (what seemed like) a simple issues for a few days now and could use some help.

I call a php file on a button-click, do a bunch of server-side operations, and wish to change a few things in the HTML at the end of the php (change images, changing text, enabling buttons, etc.)

So, what I'm trying to do (for the test case here) is change an image twice. It works fine in the first set of code (script in the html file), but it doesn't work in the second set of code (script in the php file). I.e., I see oldImage when the page loads, secondImage when I click the button, but I never see newImage.

```
<button onclick="test()">Try The Test</button>
<img id="myImage" src="oldImage.jpg">
<script> 
    function test() 
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
        img.src = 'secondImage.jpg';
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("testPhp.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Here's myPhp.php (all on one line in my code; two lines here, for readability):

```
$script = "<script> var img = document.getElementById('myImage'); 
                  img.src = 'newImage.jpg'; </script?";
echo $script;
```

Any ideas on why the script in myPhp.php doesn't work?

**EDIT:**
I changed the HTML  portion to this, then changed myPhp.php to echo "Hello World", which shows up just fine within myDiv. However, I can't seem to echo the script. Is there any way to do this?

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","portTester.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Please add the semi-colon `;` after the script to be called onclick. (My OCD...)

Comment: Did you looked at Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug? Find your request there, and look if any errors exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your ajax call returns *markup*, for it to have any effect, it has to be added to the DOM.

But I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. Instead, have your PHP file return the *information* (not a script), and then have the code receiving the information (in the `onreadystatechange` handler of the XHR object) read that information and take the relevant action.

For example, your PHP could simply return:

```
newImage.jpg
```

Then your ajax call would be:

```
function test() 
{
    var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
    img.src = 'secondImage.jpg';
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
    xmlhttp.open("testPhp.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function handleReadyStateChange() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 400) {
            // Request is complete and successful
            img.src = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to send back richer information (as is frequently the case), look at using [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: We got there at the same time! +1 for mentioning JSON :)

Comment: Thanks very much, @HeikkiU and T.J.! +1 to both and check mark to T.J., as his came in a minute earlier :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything with the response to your AJAX call. In other words: You are calling the PHP script, the reply is printed, but is thrown away, because your Javascript isn't doing anything with it. You must add some code to interact with the reply. Here's a hint: Don't try to output Javascript from PHP, output something that you USE in your Javascript.

Add this to your Javascript after the `xmlhttp.send()` call:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("myImage").src = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
}
```

And in your PHP script, put just this:

```
echo 'newImage.jpg';
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible issue is that you are missing the semi-colon after your `test()` in the `onclick`. Also, your `</script>` tag is malformed; it reads `</script?` while it should read `</script>`. Also, where into the DOM is this `echo`ing? It should go into the head of your document. Right now, it looked unspecified.

Comment: It is an AJAX request.